# "Failed" running DDEC6 Atomic Charge when using Palladium (Pd) cluster model

Tags: vasp, charge-density, metals

I have a problem with running DDEC6 when I used **Palladium (Pd)** cluster, the main issue was that there were no `DDEC6_even_templered_net_atomic_charges.xyz` files came out at all. I noticed that the **summed density is a negative value**, **which should be zero instead**. I think it is probably an error from Pd metal because I have already tried it with another metal, and it's working.

I have been trying to change the parameters in INCAR when I ran the single-point calculation from VASP to get CHGCAR and AECCAR2, but it has not worked still (for instance, changing ALGO, ISPIN, or ADDGRID).

I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me any suggestions for solving this problem.

Comment: +1 Welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future!! How did you find us?

Comment: How did this go? Any update?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP returns and expresses interest in reopening.